# Conflicting layout constraints, translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints not working

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints

First of all, this is what I want to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

The view needs to be centered, with a height of 200. The trailing an leading anchors should touch the layoutmargins. I am creating my constraints programatically.

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    var dialogView : UIView!

    func show()
    {
        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self)
        dialogView = UIView()
        dialogView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        dialogView.backgroundColor = .red
        addSubview(dialogView)

        let dialogViewCenterYConstraint = dialogView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
        dialogViewCenterYConstraint.isActive = true

        let dialogViewHeightConstraint = dialogView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        dialogViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true

        let margins = self.layoutMarginsGuide

        let dialogViewLeadingConstraint = dialogView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor)
        dialogViewLeadingConstraint.isActive = true

        let dialogViewTrailingConstraint = dialogView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor)
        dialogViewTrailingConstraint.isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CustomView().show()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

It is working, but it also prints the following warning:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x60000009ee60 h=--& v=--& ArtAlertView.CustomView:0x7f9f86c0f770.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009ed20 UIView:0x7f9f86c100d0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b8b80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009ed70 UIView:0x7f9f86c100d0.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b8b80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009eb90 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b8b80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':ArtAlertView.CustomView:0x7f9f86c0f770 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009ec30 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b8b80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':ArtAlertView.CustomView:0x7f9f86c0f770 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009ed70 UIView:0x7f9f86c100d0.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b8b80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I noticed one of the constraints is an NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint. I thought setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false would get rid of these.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show the rest of your constraints error message? And where are you running that code? I just put your code into the setup of a custom UIView, and it works fine...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added the full code and the full warning. The view is presented by calling show()

Comment: Again, I get no layout errors... when calling it from a button-tap. Where are you calling this from? And is your intent to add this view to your *current* view? It seems a rather unusual way of going about things...

Comment: Strange, CustomView().show() is called from the main viewcontroller in an IBaction function. There is no other code. I edited my post again to include every line of code in this project, now loaded in viewdidload instead. My intent is to be able to present this view easily using this single line of code from any viewcontroller, so that I reuse this custom 'AlertView' I am making in any project.

Comment: Hmm.... is it possible you're looking at the wrong thing? If you comment-out `CustomView().show()` do you still get auto-layout errors?

Comment: Nope.. I created a fresh project and copy pasted the exact code from this post and still the warning pops up in the console.

Comment: Well, I'm running out of things to suggest. I just created a new Single-View project, pasted your exact code into the view controller, and ran it. No warnings, and this is the result: https://imgur.com/QAYyKm8

Comment: I'm baffled how that is possible. perhaps it is an issue of iOS 11

Comment: I don't have a dev system handy to check iOS 11, but you may want to read through this article: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
func addSubview(_ view: UIView, with height: CGFloat = 200.0)
{
    //  Check whether superview is non-nil
    if view.superview != nil
    {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    //  Add self to view as subview
    self.addSubview(view)
    //  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is true by default, which breaks UIView.addConstraints() function
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //  Create constraints
    let centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view,
                                     attribute: .centerY,
                                     relatedBy: .equal,
                                     toItem: self,
                                     attribute: .centerY,
                                     multiplier: 1,
                                     constant: constants.top)
    let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view,
                                     attribute: .leading,
                                     relatedBy: .equal,
                                     toItem: self,
                                     attribute: .leading,
                                     multiplier: 1,
                                     constant: constants.leading)
    let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view,
                                      attribute: .trailing,
                                      relatedBy: .equal,
                                      toItem: self,
                                      attribute: .trailing,
                                      multiplier: 1,
                                      constant: constants.trailing)
    //  Add constraints to superview and return them
    self.addConstraints([top, bottom, leading, trailing])

    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view,
                                    attribute: .height,
                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                    toItem: nil,
                                    attribute: nil,
                                    multiplier: 1,
                                    constant: height)
    view.addConstraints([height])
}
```

I'm not sure that this exact text will work however (height constraint in untested). The idea is to create new constraints for `leading`, `trailing` and `centerY` and add those to your `CustomView` intance. Height constraint must be added to the `dialogView`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you create new `CustomView` without frame, when you called `show` a new `dialogView` will be added to it and layout with `|-margin-[dialogView]-margin-|`, this requires `CustomView`'s width >= `2 * margin`. so you will get this layout warning.

There are 2 way to fix this issue:

1.when you initial a new `CustomView` give it a frame where frame.width >= margin * 2.

2.give leading and trailing constraint of `dialogView` a lower layout priority.